# Self-made .csv file with lat/long - single country centroid is wrong

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3

I am projected in WGS84

I made a .csv with lat/long data for these four locations. *Yes*, I double-checked that I entered South Africas' coordinates correctly.

What is going on?

[image: https://imgur.com/a/NsIkLh4]

From some other Q&As, I'm seeing that I may need to dive into the field calculator, but why?

The coordinates *are* the real world coordinates. Again, as you can see the other country centroids place fine.

Comment: Please use the picture button to include one.

Comment: can you post the csv-file?

Comment: Don't you just have the wrong sign in front of the South African Latitude? That's what I would bet.